# How do you correct Max Draw-Down for auto-correlation?

Tags: statistics, returns, auto-correlation, performance, sharpe-ratio

When returns are auto-correlated, calculating a Sharpe ratio := $\frac {mean(x)}{\sqrt{var(x)}}$, (where $x$ are the returns) is complicated, but basically solved (see, e.g. [Lo (2005)](http://www.edge-fund.com/Lo02.pdf)). Without the correction, the Sharpe ratio is too large, b/c auto-correlation reduces the variance of the returns.

However calculating the Calmar ratio := $\frac{mean(x)}{Maxdrawdown(x)}$ with auto-correlated returns gives too small an answer b/c $Mdd(x)$ is too large.  How do you correct Mdd(x) for auto-correlation?  The answer must be quite novel, because unlike the Sharpe ratio case (where $var(x)$ is a linear statistic), $Mdd(x)$ is not a linear statistic, so the delta method cannot be employed.

Comment: Could you provide the full reference for Lo (2005)?

Comment: Wouldn't that imply that an asset or strategy with negatively  auto-correlated returns has a sharpe ratio that is too low? Is there a logical reason why returns should be "adjusted" for auto-correlation when using sharpe ratio? And if so, why not adjust for negative auto-correlation?

Comment: @Joshua Ulrich - I think he's referring to [Autocorrelation, Bias, and Fat Tails - Are Hedge Funds Really Attractive Investments?](http://papers.ssrn.com/sol3/papers.cfm?abstract_id=869769)

Comment: The reference paper is actually "The Statistics of the Sharpe Ratio" by A.Lo. Financial Analysts Journal, Vol. 58, No. 4, July/August 2002. And, as it is the statement in the question is incorrect: when returns are *positively* autocorrelated, the SR is too large. When they are *negatively* autocorrelated however, it is too small. Also, it is *Calmar* ratio, not *Calamar* ratio. And finally, it is not heavily used in practice because, being based on an extremal statistics, it has very high variance.

Answer (score 6):

Thanks gappy for your precise response. However the answer to this auto-correlation is much more important than an academic discussion of which portfolio performance ratio is best. Auto-correlation distorts max draw-down calculations raising the question of whether the (positive) auto-correlation will continue in the future producing large draw-downs, or whether it will subside to normally low levels. [ Incidentally I have never seen a negative auto-correlation in real-world monthly publicly traded asset returns.]

For example take two MLP's: the well known and large cap KMP ( a pipe-line operator) and NRGY ( a mid-cap retail propane distributor.)  On data (post Lehman) from 2/2009 to 2/2011 KMP's monthly returns are not auto-correlated, while NRGY's are highly correlated. The two Calmar ratios are: KMP= 0.1304 (StndErr=0.009); NRGY = 0.1472 (StndErr=0.25), i.e. risk-adjusted returns for the 2 assets are statistically equivalent. But if NRGY's auto-correlation is expected to subside then it's past mdd is overstated and it will be a better risk-adjusted investment than KMP in the future.

I've done some research and have been able to calculate the theoretical maxdd's for 2 models: No auto-correlation ( the much more difficult calculation) and complete auto-correlation($\rho=1$) for a no drift, normal dist. vol model, Irrespective of the size of the returns and volatility, $\rho=1$ $mdd / \rho=0$ mdd is 4.35 - - - a large difference!

In other words if period (e.g. monthly ) returns are auto-correlated you can expect a future maxdd of 4.35 times that for a normal- no auto-correlation return within the same horizon.

Auto-correlation of returns can appear in low-volume traded assets, Hedge funds,
Preferred stocks, etc. In common stocks it occurs in high-momentum assets.  In all cases of auto-correlation, BEWARE, the maxdd's will be large.  There is an easy test to determine if the returns are auto-correlated: the Ljung-Box test (Please Gappy correct my misspelling of the names if incorrect.) I have a simple R script to calculate the LB if anyone is interested.

Comment: I agree that the question is not academic, but I think you make a bold assumption when you say the maxdrawdown would be too high in autocorrelated returns, because autocorrelation would subside in the future. I think it would be important to analyse the evolution of autocorrelation in every case to see if there is a reversion to a low mean in autocorrelation or not.

Comment: I think I was misunderstood: all I am saying that with assets that exhibit autocorrelated returns, my limited experience has been that the autocorrelation condition can and does cease at some time, basically because I believe it is a temporary condition generally caused by heavy buying or demand. In these cases historical high maxdd's will not continue in the future.

Answer (score 3):

Have you considered a Monte Carlo simulation on your returns?  Then you could look at the distribution of Maximum Drawdowns.